# is there a way to disable pixman completely

Tags: x11, cairo, armv7, clutter, pixman

I have pixman installed on my arm target, for bench-marking purposes i want to disable pixman completely(if that is even possible !). Is there a way to do this nicely without actually removing it.

I know of the PIXMAN_DISABLE flag, but will that turn it off completely or just the way it works will change (like switch sse2 on or off) ?

Comment: What are you benchmarking exactly? You say you have the X11- and the egl-backend enabled, but which backend is your code using? What is it drawing?

Comment: I have a clutter-box2d app, for which i want to check FPS with and without GPU acceleration on the ARM target. pixman gives me the without GPU part. Now I am wondering how do I get the "with GPU" part. Backend refers to configuration options selected in clutter/cogl during compiles. clutter provides options to enable-egl-backend and enable-x11-backend. I have set both these flags while doing ./configure. Now, it looks like pixman is using 30% of the CPU and application is running slow(used Oprofile for profiling). So the application never got to the GPU, right?(its a simple app drawing images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cairo uses pixman for everything that the backend can't draw itself, and for everything the image backend draws. So there is no way to disable it.

Comment: I have both X11-backend and egl-backend enabled. But pixman gets used most of the time(30% of CPU-time). I am trying to make sense of it! Is it a sign of GPU not being utilized at all?

Comment: Cairo and the X11-server use pixman for their fallback drawing, too. So if cairo is using pixman a lot, you are drawing things that can't be expressed with X11/egl. If the server uses pixman, then you are drawing things that the graphics driver can't do in hardware.